# Java exe won't display specific jframe but IDE will

Tags: java, audio, netbeans, exe

I've created a mini quiz game in java and wanted to convert it to an exe..It has photos and sounds attached to it but they are in their respective folders and with the correct paths. When i click on "Insert a new question" the exe works fine, the same thing happens for the "exit" option. But when i click "Play" no window pops up but i don't get an error either..

I tried placing the photos and sounds in the same folder as the class that uses them but it didn't fix the problem. I also tried inserting ".." at the beginning of the URL paths but it didn't fix it either. I've attached the code for the not showing frame.

```
ArrayList<Question> questions;
    int selectedQuestion = 0;
    int remainingLife = 3;
    Random random = new Random();
    int fillAnswer = 0;    
    String [] answerArray = new String[4];

Clip clipSuccess;
Clip clipFailure;
Clip clipGameOver;

public static Mixer mixer;
public static Clip clip;

javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {                      

         timer.stop();
         jLabel5.setIcon(null);
         playRound();

    }
});


public PlayGame() {
    initComponents();
    questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    populateArrayList();
    clipSuccess = setSound("../Sounds/success.wav");
    clipFailure = setSound("../Sounds/failure.wav");
    clipGameOver = setSound("../Sounds/gameOver.wav");
    playRound(); 

   }

public void populateArrayList(){

    try{
       FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("Questions.dat"); 
       ObjectInputStream inputFile = new ObjectInputStream(file);

       boolean endOfFile = false;

       while(!endOfFile){

           try{

               questions.add((Question) inputFile.readObject());                   
           }
           catch(EOFException e){
               endOfFile = true;
           }
           catch(Exception f){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, f.getMessage());
           }
       }
       inputFile.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public Clip setSound(String soundPath){
    Mixer.Info[] mixInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    /*for(Mixer.Info info: mixInfos){
        System.out.println(info.getName() + "----" + info.getDescription());
    }*/
    mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixInfos[3]);

    DataLine.Info dataInfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, null);
    try {
        clip = (Clip)mixer.getLine(dataInfo);
                }
    catch(LineUnavailableException lue){
        lue.printStackTrace();            
    }

    try{
        URL soundURL = PlayGame.class.getResource(soundPath);
        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL);
        clip.open(audioStream);
    }
    catch(LineUnavailableException lue){
        lue.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uofe){
        uofe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return clip;
}



public void successAnswer(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Απάντησες σωστά!");
    jLabel5.setText("");
    jLabel5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PlayGame.class.getResource("../Images/Fireworks-animated.gif")));
    clipSuccess.setFramePosition(0);
    clipSuccess.start();        
    timer.start();
}

 public void wrongAnswer(){ 

    remainingLife--;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Απάντησες λάθος..");
    jLabel5.setText("");
    jLabel5.setIcon(new ImageIcon (PlayGame.class.getResource("../Images/failure.gif")));
    if (remainingLife == 0){
        clipFailure.setFramePosition(0);
        clipFailure.start();
        timer.start();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Δυστυχώς έχασες..");
        clipGameOver.setFramePosition(0);
        clipGameOver.start();  
        do{
            try{
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie){
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }  
        }while(clipGameOver.isActive());
        System.exit(0);
    }      
    clipFailure.setFramePosition(0);
    clipFailure.start();
    timer.start();
}

public void playRound(){
    selectedQuestion = random.nextInt(questions.size());

    jTextField3.setText(Integer.toString(remainingLife));
    jTextArea2.setText(questions.get(selectedQuestion).getQuestionName());


    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){

        fillAnswer = random.nextInt(questions.size());
        answerArray[i] = questions.get(fillAnswer).getQuestionAnswer();
        if (i==2){
            answerArray[i] = questions.get(selectedQuestion).getQuestionAnswer();
            continue;
        }        
     }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(answerArray));

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(answerArray));
}      

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int selectedAnswer = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();


    jLabel5.setIcon(null);
    if (questions.get(selectedQuestion).getQuestionAnswer().trim().equals(answerArray[selectedAnswer].trim())){
        successAnswer();            
    } 
    else{
        wrongAnswer();
    }    

    timer.start();


}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    System.exit(0);
```

In the IDE the output is a jframe with a question, a combo box of 4 answers, the player's life points and two buttons (one for locking the answer and one for exiting the program). But in the exe form it doesn't even pop up.

---

EDIT - This is the error the wrapper program shows:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout
    at quiz.PlayGame.initComponents(PlayGame.java:277)
    at quiz.PlayGame.(PlayGame.java:62)

Comment: What OS are you running this on? How are you building the app? What is the file structure like around the runable? Also where is your main method? What version of netbeans?

Comment: I'm running this on windows 10 and using netbeans 10 , i built the app using Launch4j (with a clean build of the jar file) setting the minimum java to 1.6.0, my main class just makes the menu visible and through the menu you can either choose the above option, or two other ones that run correctly

Comment: After reading the error i found out that the error was me forgetting to attach the classpath for the absolute layout....